If-else logic in C language homework
The question was related to the if-else topic. I tried to create a program where a person inputs their income and the program shows how much tax they need to pay.
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    float tax, income;

    printf("Kindly note down your income here\n");
    scanf("%f", income);

    if (income < 5.0 && income > 2.5)
    {
        printf("You have to pay 5 tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }
    else if (income < 10.0 && income > 5.0)
    {
        printf("You have to pay 20 tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }
    else if (income > 10.0)
    {        
        printf("You have to pay 30 tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }
    else if (income < 2.5)
    {
        printf("You have to pay no tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }

    return 0;
}

This is what I tried. where am I wrong?

scanf("%f",income); needs fo tm scanf("%f",&income);

(1) Test the value returned by scanf() and family to ensure you got the input you were expecting.  (2) One of the simplest debugging techniques is to print the value that the program read (or was supposed to have read) so you can compare it with what you expected it to get.  (3) Make sure you compile with warnings enabled.  If you use GCC, then a good starting point is gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra …, but you can get fussier if you want.

Your original question title was not good.  It was all circumstantial information, not a description of the real problem.  The body of the question should identify what goes wrong — you should have told us what output you get for a sample input.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages (again).

What if income equals to 5.0 for example?

Guys... we need not answer the endless FAQ of misplaced & in scanf. If you need a canonical dupe, then this is one: What will happen if '&' is not put in a 'scanf' statement? But these should really just be clobbered as "simply typo". Every single C beginner makes these bugs and they are best addressed by paying closer attention to the beginner learning materials, chapter 1.

While Allan Wind has identified the source of your error, I would further suggest you refactor your conditional by changing the order to reduce the things you need to test for because you can assume all previous conditions tested are false.
    if (income < 2.5) {
        printf("You have to pay no tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }
    // We now *know* that income >= 2.5
    else if (income < 5.0) {
        printf("You have to pay 5 tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }
    else if (income < 10.0) {
        printf("You have to pay 20 tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }
    else {
        printf("You have to pay 30 tax because your income is %f\n", income);
    }

Though it is not relevant to this very simple example, using floating point numbers to work with money is questionable, but using single-precision floating point numbers (vs. double) is especially dubious, as money can involve large numbers which make single-precision numbers rapidly become imprecise, leading to errors in calculations. Few classes of arithmetic errors upset people more than those involving money.
Since the conditionals are exhaustive (a branch is always executed) there is no need to initialize tax when it is declared.
Modifying Allan Wind's suggested code for this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf("Kindly note down your income here: ");
    double income;
    int rv = scanf("%lf", &income);
    if(rv != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    double tax;
    if (income < 2.5) 
        tax = 0;
    else if (income < 5.0) 
        tax = 5;
    else if (income < 10.0) 
        tax = 20;
    else 
        tax = 30;

    // Or even just:
    // double tax = (income <  2.5) ?  0 :
    //              (income <  5.0) ?  5 :
    //              (income < 10.0) ? 20 : 30;

    if (tax)
        printf("You have to pay %.2f tax because your income is %.2f\n", tax, income);
    else
        printf("You have to pay no tax because your income is %.2f\n",  income);
}

